# Django contrib auth users manytomany

Tags: django, django-models

Hello I want to make several users to one post with `manytomany` relationship.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    body = models.TextField()
```

But I got this error

```
Post needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.
```

Can anyone tell me what the problem is?

Comment: Please add an error traceback in order to make it more clear.

Comment: are there some post already present in database

Comment: Not yet base is clear

Comment: Can you share the view/form code

Answer (score 0):

In order to setup a many-to-many relationship the ID of the post is mandatory. Check in your database if the post(s) has an ID. The error message says its empty, so add it manually in the database (not recommended) or rerun the post its migrations and make sure the ID is auto-incremented.